# In planar graph, for any vertex v, it's possible to find an embedding in which v is in unbounded face

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

As mentioned in title, I am wondering..

Assume G is a planar graph and pick any vertex v.

1. Is is possible to find a planar embedding in which v is in an unbounded face?
2. What if we add a constraint that v is the vertex which is connected to all other vertices?

Thank you in advance.

I encountered this problem when I solved a question in Introduction to Graph Theory by West.

[Reference - Solution to a problem in Intro to Graph Theory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnAdD.png)

Comment: The question in the duplicate is slightly different but the answer solves the problem just as well: given any plane embedding of $G$, we can pick any face $f$ and get a new plane embedding of $G$ in which $f$ is the unbounded face. See Remark 6.1.27 in your textbook for a bit more detail.